# Javascript to Typescript Objection.js transaction / query functions not found

Tags: javascript, typescript, objection.js

I'm converting a Javascript project to Typescript. I'm using Objection.js. The issue is, Typescript is unable to find typing information for the Objection.js built-in transaction and query functions. I have the following type dev dependencies:

```
    "@types/knex": "^0.16.1",
    "@types/koa": "^2.13.4",
    "@types/koa-bodyparser": "^4.3.7",
    "@types/koa-json": "^2.0.20",
    "@types/koa-logger": "^3.1.2",
    "@types/koa-passport": "^4.0.3",
    "@types/koa-router": "^7.4.4",
    "@types/node": "^18.0.0",
    "@types/node-os-utils": "^1.3.0",
    "@types/statuses": "^2.0.0",
```

Here's the code I'm having issues with. Both the transaction and query functions are not found by Typescript. The specific error is ts(2339) "Property 'transaction' does not exist on type User" as well as "Property 'query' does not exist on type User".

```
  async getOne(ctx): Promise<ResponseType> {
    const userId = ctx.params.id;
    if (!ctx.isAuthenticated() || !ctx.req.user.canActAs(userId)) {
      return { status: status('Unauthorized') };
    }
    const idSchema = Joi.number().positive();

    try {
      // Error is on this line:
      const returnValue = await User.transaction(async (trx) => {
        await idSchema.validateAsync(userId);

        // Error is on this line:
        const user = await User.query(trx)
          .where('id', userId)
          .select(ctx.query.select ? ctx.query.select : null)
          .first();
        const returnedUser = ctx.req.user.isAdmin() ? user : user.filtered();
        return { status: status('OK'), body: returnedUser };
      });

      return returnValue;
    } catch (error) {
      logger.error(error);
      return {
        status: status('Internal Server Error'),
        message: 'Error',
      };
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to change the User import from:

`import User = require('../../database/models/User');`

to

`import User from '../../database/models/User';`

and that fixed the issue.